# reorder panda data frame columns vertical

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a bit new to panda and have some diabetic data that i would like to reorder.

[image]

I'd like to copy the data from column `'wakeup'` through `'23:00:00'`, 
and put this data vertical under each other so I would get a new dataframe  column:

```
5.6  
8.1  
9.9   
6.3  
4.1  
13.3  
NAN  
3.9  
3.3  
6.8  
.....etc
```

Comment: I think `.melt`, to preserve `NaN`. There are examples in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376053/pandas-dataframe-stack-multiple-column-values-into-single-column

Comment: Any NAN should stay as NAN here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself finally took me quite some time. 
Notice here the orginal data was in df1 result in dfAllMeasurements

```
dfAllMeasurements = df1.loc[:, 'weekday':'23:00:00']
temp = dfAllMeasurements.set_index('weekday','ID').stack(dropna=False) #dropna = keeping NAN 
dfAllMeasurements = temp.reset_index(drop=False, level=0).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the data is in a dataframe already. You can index the columns you want and then use `melt` as suggested. Without any parameters, `melt` will 'stack' all your data into one column of a new dataframe. There's another column created to identify the original column names, but you can drop that if needed.

```
df.loc[:, 'wakeup':'23:00:00'].melt()
```

```
    variable  value
0     wakeup    5.6
1     wakeup    8.1
2     wakeup    9.9
3     wakeup    6.3
4     wakeup    4.1
5     wakeup   13.3
6     wakeup    NAN
7   09:30:00    3.9
8   09:30:00    3.3
9   09:30:00    6.8
...
```

You mention you want this as another column, but there's no way to sensibly add it into your existing dataframe. The shape likely won't match also.

Comment: your right on that it should indeed be in a new dataset, note though that in your list the wakeups are all below each, its not what i want.