# Stack multiple columns into one single column in a csv with Python 3.x

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a large CSV file with multiple columns that I would like to merge into 2 columns using Python.

What I have:

```
ID.12345        ID.45678
CVE-xxxx-1234   CVE-xxxx-5678
CVE-xxxx-3456
```

What I need:

```
ID         CVE
ID.12345   CVE-xxxx-1234
ID.12345   CVE-xxxx-3456
ID.45678   CVE-xxxx-5678
```

I looked through several solutions here but not sure where to start (coding n00b). [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376053/pandas-dataframe-stack-multiple-column-values-into-single-column) looks closest to what I need but the data is already in a Pandas dataframe at the start while I only have the csv. Do I need Pandas? Do I need to create a dataframe from the csv file? Can this be done using only Python's csv library? HELP

P.S. The csv has 1000+ columns if that is of any significance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your expected result run:

```
result = df.melt(var_name='ID', value_name='CVE').dropna()
```

The result, for your data sample is:

```
         ID            CVE
0  ID.12345  CVE-xxxx-1234
1  ID.12345  CVE-xxxx-3456
2  ID.45678  CVE-xxxx-5678
```

Comment: Just to clarify for any other n00bs out there, first I needed to:
import csv
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

and run the code above :)

Comment: No need to *import csv*. Note that *read_csv* is a *pandasonic* method.