# Combining the Rows of All Columns into a Single Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

[Example Pandas DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA8db.png)

How do you combine all the rows in all columns into a single column? I would like to append the rows in C2 and C3 to C1. That is, have one column, C1, with 15 rows, each with their respective values.

Comment: Please include any code and errors as formatted text not images meta.https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376053/pandas-dataframe-stack-multiple-column-values-into-single-column

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a new DataFrame from the `reshape`d numpy array underlying the original DataFrame, using `order='F'` to stack columns on top of each other:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1, order='F'), 
                      columns=['C1'])
```

Relevant section of the [`numpy.reshape` documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

> **order : *{‘C’, ‘F’, ‘A’}, optional***
>
> Read the elements of a using this index
> order, and place the elements into the reshaped array using this index
> order. ‘C’ means to read / write the elements using C-like index
> order, with the last axis index changing fastest, back to the first
> axis index changing slowest. **‘F’ means to read / write the elements
> using Fortran-like index order, with the first index changing fastest,
> and the last index changing slowest**

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `pd.DataFrame.melt`:

```
df.melt()
```

Output:

```
   variable value
0        C1     A
1        C1     B
2        C1     C
3        C1     D
4        C1     E
5        C2     F
6        C2     G
7        C2     H
8        C2     I
9        C2     J
10       C3     K
11       C3     L
12       C3     M
13       C3     N
14       C3     O
```