# How to transform pandas dataframe from 5x3 to 15x1?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe of 3 columns by 5 rows.  I would like to make it be one column of 15 rows by putting the second column below the first, and the third below the second.  Something like:

```
[1,2,3,
 4,5,6,
 7,8,9,
 10,11,12,
 13,14,15]
```

would turn into:

```
[1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9,
10,
11,
12,
13,
14,
15]
```

Is there a cleaner, quicker way to do this than calling df.append multiple times?  In reality I will have to do this for dozens of columns, not just three.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376053/pandas-dataframe-stack-multiple-column-values-into-single-column

Comment: Flattening it is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.to_numpy().flatten()
```

will do exactly this